# Can I connect directly to the output of a Mahout model with other data-related tools?

Tags: mahout

My only experience with Machine Learning / Data Mining is via SQL Server Analysis Services.

Using SSAS, I can set up models and fire direct singleton queries against it do to things like real-time market basket analysis and product suggestions. I can grab the "results" from the model as a flattened resultset and visualize same elsewhere.

Can I connect directly to the output of a Mahout model with other data-related tools in the same manner? For example, is there any way I can pull out a tabular resultset so I can render same with the visualization tool of my choice? ODBC driver, maybe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of Mahout is generally a file on HDFS, though you could dump it out anywhere Hadoop can put data. And with another job to translate to put in whatever form you need, it's readable. And if you can find an ODBC driver for the data store you put it in, yes.

So I suppose the answer is, no, there is not by design any integration with any particular consumer. But you can probably hook up whatever you imagine.

There are some bits that are designed to be real-time systems queried via API, but I don't think it's what you mean.

Comment: Thanks - I assumed Mahout wasn't quite mainstream enough (outside the data mining / big data community) to actually warrant these sorts of connectivity options. I actually had never heard about it until yesterday - sounds like a fun project I'll need to spend some time with.